# csvで文字列が日付になる問題

Tags: python, csv

Pythonでcsv出力処理を行なっているのですが
「１ー１」で出力すると日付になってしまいます

例えば、エクセルで「１ー１」を手入力すると１月１日になると思います。そうではなく「１ー１」のまま出力されたいです。

頭に‘をつけると文字列として認識してくれるのですが、プログラムで「’」+文字列でやるとただの文字列連結になって、「‘１ー１」になってしまいます。日付問題は解消されますが、頭に‘がついています。

うまく「１ー１」を出力する方法ないでしょうか

プログラムは仕事の関係でお見せすることが出来ず申し訳ありません。

Comment: それはCSVデータの問題ではなくExcelの問題だという認識で合っていますか？

Comment: 表現が悪くすみません。csvデータは問題ないですね、エクセルで開いたときに日付になっていますね。エクセルで開いても１ー１になるようにプログラムでなんとかする方法はありますでしょうか

Comment: 顧客が求めているものがエクセルで処理できるデータ形式であればいっそエクセルファイルを出力してしまうという方法もあります。https://gammasoft.jp/blog/openpyxl-vs-pandas/

Comment: ありがとうございます。結局、プログラムの修正なしで、エクセルで書式変換の設定で対応することになりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSVファイルへの出力は、たとえば

```
1-1,2-2,3-3
```

で良いです。CSVファイル形式としてはこれで合っています。

問題は、Excelがこのデータを読み込んだとき、そのセルの書式が勝手に日付になることだと思いますが、どうやって読み込んでいますか？

私の手元にあるのはMicrosoft Office 2013のExcel 2013ですが、空でもいいから何かブックを開き、「データ」タブの「外部データの取り込み」の「テキストファイル」を選ぶとファイル選択ダイアログが出て、そこで上記のCSVファイルを選ぶとテキストファイルウィザードが出て、元のデータの形式、区切り文字、区切ったあとの列のデータ形式を細かく指定することができます。列のデータ形式で文字列を選択すれば、余計な変換は行われません。

Comment: そうなんですよね、これは読み込み時に対応するしかないですね、実は仕事のことでユーザからエクセルを開いたとき文字列になるようにしてほしいと言われました。csvは正しく出力されているので、プログラム修正で対応するより、読み込み時に設定してもらうしかないですかね

Comment: @入江哲志  CSV ファイルに書式が定義されているわけではないので、 Excel で単純に「開く」だとおせっかいで意図しない変換が発生します。ですので「データの取り込み」の方がおすすめです。

Comment: 承知しました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

古い記事だけど, データ交換時のポイントや, CSVの公式仕様的なドキュメントへのリンクがあります

- [CSVファイルフォーマットの解説](https://codezine.jp/article/detail/2364)

wikipedia にも https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-Separated_Values

それを踏まえた上で, 以下のドキュメントに 各種のパラメーターが載ってるので, それを利用するとよいかもです

(docs.python.org) [csv --- CSV ファイルの読み書き](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/csv.html)

- 区切り文字(`delimiter`)
- 引用符文字(`quotechar`)
- 引用符(`quoting`) … `quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`, `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` など

`quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` あるいは `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` 指定すれば可能かも？

---

たぶんエクセル側にも, 読み込み時の指定が可能なはずだと推測されます
(カンマ区切りとかタブ区切りとか, 引用符付いてれば文字列にするとか)

Python側の出力変えてもうまく行かない場合には
それらの設定も考慮するとよいかも

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。参考にしてみます。